# How to query TFS tickets I have been mentioned @tagged in?

Tags: tfs, azure-devops

Presently I use my email notifications to manage TFS tickets that have a comment which I have been @mentioned on.

Is there a way to query for comments that include mentions of me? I want to ensure I am commenting back on all TFS tickets directed at me using a @mention.

Answer (score 7):

`ID in @RecentMentions` gives you all work items where “I am mentioned” in the discussion section.

[image: Recent mentions]